# Invisible symbols in the Boston Gate Lantern Underground puzzle

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I am stuck in the Boston gate magic lantern puzzle in the PC version of Assassins Creed 3.

The one I'm talking about is the one farthest to the left. I know **how** you are supposed to solve the puzzle, the problem is I can't seem to see the symbols. I have all the other doors unlocked except for this one.

I mean instead of seeing this:
[image]

I see it without the symbols. Pretty much what the door used to look like, almost like this 
[image]

but zoomed in and with the directions like you would normally get

Is it a glitch? If so, what can I do about it?

Comment: Do you have any details? What do you mean by you can't see the symbols? (It should look [like this](http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/s_dQfTXpB6c/mqdefault.jpg), video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_dQfTXpB6c).)

Comment: What platform are you playing on?

Comment: why didn't you post a screenshot while using the item to see the symbols and move them?

Comment: You could try changing the options/filters, both in game and for the graphics card. Chances are that turning off an option will give you a lower quality effect that works.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this once on the PS3 version. Rebooting my system solved it for me. I'm not sure how saving on the PC version works--you might want to try leaving the sewers, saving, rebooting, then going back into the sewers to see if that fixes it.